# Can only see one of my two layers - and they have different CRSs

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to plot data from a CSV file onto vegetation map (a .tif file). When I upload both layers into my project, the vegetation map comes up, however the CSV file (that should come up as small crosses for each datapoint) is not visible.

I think this is due to the difference in CRS, but I'm completely new to QGIS so I can't quite figure it out.

The Project CRS is **WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N**.

The .tif vegetation map file CRS is **EPSG:32637 – WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N**.

The .csv data CRS is **EPSG:4326 – WGS 84**.

Is it enough for me to simply change the .csv data CRS to "**Project CRS: EPSG:32637 – WGS 84 / UTM zone 37N**" (one of the three CRS options)?

This does cause the data points to show up, but I don't know if this will cause my CSV data to be projected incorrectly?

(QGIS version 3.16.3-Hannover)

Comment: Changing the CRS only changes the metadata not the data - leave the CRS as it was and everything will line up if the values are correct.,

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand what you mean by 'leave the CRS as it was' – are you suggesting I don't change anything?

Comment: Your data has a CRS associated with it - don't change that (except in the unlikely event that it has been provided with the wrong CRS set)

Comment: So then how do I solve the issue of not being able to see the den locations if changing the assigned CRS for the .csv file is not the solution?

Comment: When you "**change** the CRS" you are likely *corrupting* the dataset. What you need to do is **project** the dataset to the common CRS.  This should happen automatically on draw (due to on-the-fly reprojection), so this is likely an issue of having the wrong metadata to start.  Please [Edit] the Question to state what the min/max X&Y values are in each layer, in addition to what their CRS is.

Comment: Ah okay yes corrupting the dataset was my concern. Not to sound completely incompetent, but where would I find the min/max X&Y values? The textboxes on the Metadata page of Properties for each layer is empty.